# not able to execute Yum nor update Yum in Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: unix, amazon-web-services, suse

I am not able to execute Yum nor update Yum in Amazon EC2 instance

When ever i execute Yum.. it throws an exception

"sudo: yum: command not found"

Please tell me how to install yum in Amazon EC2 instance

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install yum on a suse system the command would be:

```
zypper install yum
```

You don't need yum to update the system however, you can just run:

```
zypper up
```

Either command needs to be run as root, or you can prepend it with the 'sudo' command if your user is in the sudoers file.

As mentioned above, zypper is the default package manager on suse/opensuse, here's a handy cheat-sheet:

https://en.opensuse.org/images/1/17/Zypper-cheat-sheet-1.pdf